# how to manually set data for a column in database which has "Datetime" type?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I have a column in my database which its type is `date`.

Now I want to manually fill the database. Actually the problem is when I manually type `13/8/2013`, it alerts

> the value in this cell is not known as "Datetime"

How can I manually set this column?

Comment: I would suggest looking up `DateTime` formats and how to convert `DataTime` in C# to fit the format of the database that you are currently using and or working with..

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date format is `yyyy-MM-dd`.

```
2013-08-13
```

BTW from the error message it looks like the column type is `datetime` and not `date`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this: 2013-08-11 00:00:00.000  (YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:mmm)

Comment: The reason for using this format is that it's easier to compare dates as strings if the RDBMS does not any Date/Time type.